# chosen combobox jquery library update text

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

hello guys i have two combobo boxes in my page and i 'm using the chosen() jquery library. 
Now would i like to do is swap the text from combo1 to combo2 .
 I have tried something like this.

```
var startint = $("#StartLocations").attr("selectedIndex");
        var endint = $("#EndLocations").attr("selectedIndex");

        $("#EndLocations").attr("selectedIndex", startint);
        $("#StartLocations").attr("selectedIndex", endint);
        $('#StartLocations').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

where end location and start location is the name of the comboboxes.
 any ideas how i might acomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that when chosen library takes over it essentially hides the select object and puts in an span with a text from the select from the hidden select. the trick i used to actually change the text was to simply go after the span under that specific object. so in other words something like this.

```
        var StartNode = $("#StartLocations").val();
        var EndNode = $("#EndLocations").val();        
        $("#StartLocations_chzn a > span").text( EndNode);
        $("#EndLocations_chzn a > span").text(StartNode);
```

Hopefully this helps some other noob.
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Combobox values can be retrieved and set using .val() function.

HTML:

```
<select id="a">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<button id="switch">Switch</button>
```

JavaSript:

```
$("#switch").click(function(){
    var valA = $("#a").val();
    var valB = $("#b").val();
    $("#a").val(valB);
    $("#b").val(valA);
});
```

See this fiddle to example: http://jsfiddle.net/lopisan/Exf4Y/

Comment: sorry but these comboboxes are getting turned into input boxes by the chosen library to have the autosuggest functionality i have already tried what you suggested thanks for the response but thats not what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Miguel's answer to his own question would work but it does tie you in rather to the specific markup which chosen outputs.

An alternative approach, which is still tied to chosen but at least uses its JavaScript API rather than trawling through the markup, is to update the select box as lopisan suggested but then fire the proprietary `liszt:updated` event. Something like this:

```
$("#switch").click(function(){
  var valA = $("#a").val();
  var valB = $("#b").val();
  $("#a").val(valB);
  $("#b").val(valA);
  $("#a").trigger("liszt:updated");
  $("#b").trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```